# A closed set contains all its limit points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm constructing a proof regarding a closed set $Y$. In it, I make the assumption that $Y$ is not closed. This means that $Y$ does not contain all its limit points $k_0$. Does this then mean, that one of these points $k_0$ must instead be a isolated point? Since, If I have understood this correctly, the opposite of a limit point is an isolated point. In general, what does it mean when a set does **not** contain all its limit points?

Comment: Not at all.  Consider for example $(0,1)$.  Both $0$ and $1$ are limit points of this set.  But they are not isolated points.

Comment: Indeed every limit point is a point of closure but the converse does not hold always, a point of closure which is not a limit point is called an isolated point, and the set containing all of such isolated points is called **derived set** which is closed itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not imply there exists at least one isolated point.

The assumption that a set does not contain all its limit points implies there exist a limit point of the set not in the set, not "not all points in the set are limit points".

Answer (score 2):

You idea of “opposite” here is a bit confused.

Say we have a set $S$.  A point $p$ could be

1. In $S$, or not in $S$
2. A limit point of $S$, or not a limit point of $S$

*All four combinations are possible*.  Consider the set $$S = [0, 1) \cup \{2\}.$$  Then examples of each of the four combinations of properties are:

$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
& \text{in $S$} & \text{not in $S$} \\ \hline
\text{limit point} & 0 & 1 \\
\text{not limit point} & 2 & 3 \\
\end{array}
$$

Every point in the line is one of these four types.   The points $0$ and $2$ are in $S$, but $0$ is a limit point and $2$ is not.  The points $1$ and $3$ are not in $S$, but $1$ is a limit point and $3$ is not.

Points of type $2$ are called *isolated points*.  They are exactly those points that are in $S$ but are not limit points of $S$.

You can see in the chart that "limit point" is not really the "opposite" of "isolated point".  That *is* true for points of $S$ (types $0$ and $2$).  But a point of type $3$ is neither a limit point of $S$ nor an isolated point of $S$.

When there are *no* points of type $1$, we say that $S$ is *closed*.  If $S$ is *not* closed, then that means there *is* a point of type $1$.  But that has no bearing on whether there is an isolated point, which is about whether there are any points of type $2$.  There could be points of both types, or neither, or points of one type but not the other.